# Why does declaring with a class take more memory than a struct?

Tags: .net-core, memory

I have a question about the memory model for .NET Core. First, a simple test:

I created a simple class "MyType" with 3 props:

```
int a;
int b;
double c;
```

I created a `List<MyType`, reserved 1 million elements, and filled it:

```
List<MyType> someList = new List<MyType>(1000000);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    someList.Add(new MyType());
}
```

Now if I use a class for the "MyType" declaration, the program consumes 42 MB of memory. When using a struct, it consumes 25 MB.

Knowing that class is located on the heap and that the build is x86 Release, each of my objects stored on the heap should have an address store overhead of 4 bytes. This means that 1 million objects should create 4 MB "overhead", and thus I would expect the classes to consume 29 MB, not 42 MB.

What's causing the difference in memory consumption here?

Comment: Hi @MK_Gii, welcome to SO. A small hint for you. Replace the list with an array of the same type and check if it makes a difference. Then create a struct with the same fields (int, int, double) and do a test again, but use struct.

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev since the list is pre-sized in this case, it should be comparable

Comment: Tried using MyType[] someList instead List<MyType> - got the same results. 25MB for structs and 42MB for classes... doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't accounting for the object header size, which is 8 bytes per object on x86; so that's another 8MB; 29 + 8 = 37, which is closer; then add some padding in the allocation areas.

The object header is the metadata that sits *before* every heap-allocated `object` instance to say what the type is, etc.

A struct (when not boxed, etc) does not have an object header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Marc. Could you elaborate a bit more about the obj header? I thought a 32bit (x86) has a 4 byte header (4 * 8 = 32). In other words address space for it. How come it's 8 bytes? Also shouldn't the realease build clear up the padding? meaning that CLR keeps objects compact on the memory space and the process should (in theory) not consume more memory than required?

Comment: @MK_Gii the 32-bit thing you're talking about is the reference, not the object header. A reference to a class doesn't point to the first data field; it points to the object header, which is an *extra* chunk of data *before* the fields. The object header contains two things; a: access to the method table and type metadata (what are you?), and b: the "sync block"; the sync block is a set of flags etc that control runtime behaviour such as GC - and also help with things like "lock" IIRC. Recall that an "object someRef" can point to any object, and it needs to work (GetType(), type check, etc).

Comment: @MK_Gii so: the object header is what makes all that work. It also makes virtual calls work *effeciently*  in the case of polymorphism - the v-table is available from the object-header. Padding is nothing to do with release builds. Padding is used to avoid misaligned memory access (which can be much slower); there will also be some unavoidable wastage since allocations happen in blocks, and you won't always fit an exact number of objects on a page.